# React Router Props Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using reactjs and react router in my web project, and I'm getting an error, here is the code.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import NewuserInfo from './NewUserInfomationComponent'

class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/new/user/:pid" component={NewuserInfo}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**NewUserInfomationComponent.js**

```
class NewUserInfomationComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ddiabetes: moment(),
        pid: this.props.params.pid,
        pmh : {},
        pmh_con: '',
        pmh_date: '',
        pmh_mng: ''
    }

}
```

In the following code when running I'm getting an error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing props to the `constructor`. `constructor` takes `props` as first argument and `context` as the second.